# Bluetooth headphones not connecting on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, bluetooth, headphones

I have FINGERS Chic BT5 bluetooth earphones with bluetooth version 5. I am unable to pair it with Ubuntu. Whenever I try to connect, it simply does not connect.

Sometimes it shows connected (I don't know how) but it is not actually connected as I don't get any voice from earphones and I can't seem to find my earphones in output devices.

LMP version in my ubuntu is 4.2(0x8)

[image: image of bluetooth connections]

[image: Image for device output when it shows it is connected to earphones]

Please help, I'm new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Does the Bluetooth device in the computer support version 5?

Comment: @David I have hp 245 g7 laptop. I'm not sure but I think it should support bluetooth 5

Comment: You may want to check 5 is very new. In the local stores here in Sweden 5 is not available yet.